# How to insert row into dataframe with row name?

Tags: r

Here is the code, but I don't know where to set the rowname

```
df = data.frame(col1= numeric(0), col2= integer(0))
df = rbind(df,c(1,2))
```

Comment: Like this `df = rbind(df,rowname=c(1,2))`?

Answer (score 0):

I write my comment as an answer so that you can accept it if it meets your needs.

Try naming the desired row inside of `rbind`

```
df = rbind(df,rowname=c(1,2))
```